# What should I do after drawing spells?

Tags: wizards-unite

After drawing a spell during an encounter, there's a circle that the spell seems to rotate around. Is there some kind of action expected with this, like tapping or holding it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you referring to the spell circle in a fortress? Or, is this a regular encounter? Can you provide a screen shot?

Comment: @GameLikeBeaker I'm not sure about fortresses, but definitely regular encounters.

Comment: Ahh, That's just the animation of your spell hitting the target, there is nothing to do with that really (at least from what I've seen). I can't find any official documentation

Comment: @GameLikeBeaker Ah, so similar to Pokemon Go having the Pokeball twitch and blink before capture.

Comment: Yes, exactly like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing a bit longer I can answer this anecdotally.

The swirling circles that you see after the spell has been cast is an indication of the spell is going to success or fail.

From what it look like, it will turn more red if the spell is failing and then when you succeed, it turns blue/white/purple colors.

As per our comment discussion, this is similar to the animation in Pokemon Go where the ball jiggles and wiggles until it shows you've caught it or not, just prettier!

Again, this is all anecdotal evidence, be nice if there were some hard references to associate.

Comment: I also noticed that failures tend to have the circle shrinking while successes tend to have it getting bigger.

Comment: I think it's fair to note that red and black circles do not automatically indicate failure, but I believe the likelihood of failure is higher the longer they appear.